# VideoJS nteraction doesn't fire google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, video.js

I am trying to use the videoJS tracker on google tag manager. 
I have followed instruction from a blog on creating tags ( with custom html) , triggers and variables from the data layer.
Now the custom html videojs listener works but when i click on play / pause the videdojs interaction doesn't fire. The data doesn't seem to be push on the data layer too. 
I have attached a screen shoot down here.

Not sure how to unblock this and what could be the problem.

[image]

Edit:

I add a link of the json I loaded

[Download the json to load inside the GTM](https://www.wcg.de/fileadmin/masterTemplate/Resources/Public/Files/site-wcg/blog/tag-manager-video-js.zip)

Also I am looking at the developer and I see some message like this :

VIDEOJS: Play middleware has been registered with videojs

and I can see some action. It seems that it's calling another api.

[image]
I will ask the web dev later it might help to understand

Comment: Can you share a link to a JSBin or other location where your sample code resides? There could be many reasons the beacon is not firing.

Comment: @MichaelArguin I just added a link to the json a loaded. I will in any case ask the web developer to understand what is happening behind the scene. It seems that videojs is acting as a middleware maybe that's why it's not firing.

Comment: Do you also have a link to the player somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I understood why the event was not triggering.
Basically the trigger was on page load and when on page load window.videojs.players is empty so it cannot track correctly. I change the trigger to all clicks to able to track correctly.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!